# JDBC insert data into MySql table from txt file

Tags: mysql, database, jdbc, insert, auto-increment

I want to read data from txt file and insert them into a mysql database but i get error int the sql syntax.Μy sql code is given below:

```
`Statement stmt = null;
     
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        // STEP 3: Open a connection
        System.out.print("\nConnecting to database...");
        java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println(" SUCCESS!\n");
    
        stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
    
        String sql = "INSERT INTO `data_db` (location , instrument,date_time,data)"+
        " VALUES ('" + location + "','" + instrument + "',''" + date_time + "','" + blob + "')";
        
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

`

What is the problem?
location, instrument, date_time and blob are strings...
The table has an id column that is auto-incremented...

Comment: could you print your `sql` out and given the error message details please?

Answer (score 1):

Could you share the error message of the sql code?

AFAIK, it may be a redundant single quote between your `instrument` and `date_time` variables.